# Android system service permissions

Tags: android, linux, android-service, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I want to develop a system service for Android application using tutorial http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_SystemService. Question is whether created system service will have permissions to read/write to /dev/block/ directory.

And where can I get more information about permissions and rights of system services.

Comment: To get access for system services you should create custom ROM.Here you can read about it.http://source.android.com/

Comment: If I do that, the access to mentioned directory will be guaranteed?

Comment: Yes.if you set correct permission to this folder